# Video kept playing even after closing modal in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to make a process where a video will be played in a modal once it is clicked and the video will be paused when the modal is closed. But the video kept playing even if I close the modal . My codes are :

```xml
<div class="modal fade aspire-video-modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-top: 37px;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  
                    allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer col-1 align-self-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary aspire-video-close" data- 
                dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And script codes are :

```sh
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.video-btn', function(){
        event.preventDefault();

        let id = $(this).data('id');

        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/watchvideo/"+id,
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(getVideo){
                var d = getVideo.video_link;
                console.log(d);
                $('#video').html(getVideo.video_link);
                // $("#video").attr('src',$getVideo.video_link);
                $("#video").attr("src", d+"? 
                autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0");

                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
        })
    });

    $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $("#video").pause();
    });
});
```

Comment: is this a vimeo video??

Comment: @KenLee I have tried your, still not working

Comment: @zahidhasanemon it's playing in iframe (a youtube video)

Comment: I suggest you use the following javascript to load a blank page to stop the video:  `$('#video').html('blank.html');` (but make sure you have a blank.html file)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap. This is a YouTube modal I have working on my site, it may help you. Try implementing it.

**Modal HTML**

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: transparent; border:none;">
            <div class="modal-header p-0 m-0" style="background-color: transparent!important;border:none!important;">
                <button type="button" class="close pr-3" data-dismiss="modal" style="color:white;">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body p-0" style="background-color: transparent;">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="border-radius: 10px;width:100%;max-width:900px;">
                    <iframe id="dash-video"
                    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QDVLMegSnBQ" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" 
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            
            // -- script to stop the video from playing when closing modal ---
            var url = $("#dash-video").attr('src');
            
            $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
                $("#dash-video").attr('src', '');
            });
            
            $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
                $("#dash-video").attr('src', url);
            });
 });
```

**Note1:** Position this code at the end before the `</body>` tag.

**Note2:** Maybe try it with my video and then make the necessary adjustments to display your video.

Comment: can I use this in ajax ?

Comment: Why are you using ajax? Could you explain what you are doing?

Comment: I am not getting the youtube video url in the modal (onclick) from the component, that's why I am using another ajax call in order to get the video for that specific component

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating things. I will upload my YouTube modal to the answer. If it works for me it should work for you.

Comment: ok sure, thanks for your help and time (in advance)

Comment: it's saying undefined (for the video link)  . I am sharing my inspect :  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src=(unknown) id="video" allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>

Comment: Did my video work? your iframe does not have a src url...